# Predicate on Arraylist

Tags: java, android, arraylist, predicate

I have two array list as per below structure :

```
Arraylist A ::

{name : name1,
number : 1234
},
{name : name2,
number : 4567
},
{name : name3,
number : 6789
}

Arraylist B ::

{number : 1234,
userId : u1
},
{number : 4567
userId : u2
},
{number : 6789
userId : u3
}
```

Now I need to merge two array in a following manner :

```
Arraylist C ::

{name : name1,
number : 1234,
userId : u1
},
{name : name2,
number : 4567,
userId : u2
},
{name : name3,
number : 6789,
userId : u3
}
```

How to achieve this with predicate? Can anyone please help.?

Actual scenario is like i have an array list of **contacts from device contact** book which contains **name, number, emailId** and when i sync those contacts with my **app serve**r i get **number, userId and Image Url** in return. Now i need to map number with these two array and need to generate **common array** which contains all the details like **number,name, emailId, userId, Image Url**.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i think using dictionary is better approach for this situation.

Comment: What are the types of the elements? Are they just ```Map```'s ?

Comment: @JornVernee - They are of Entity (Model) type. here is just a brief structure demonstartion as i can't print entity class here

Answer (score 0):

I made this utility function yesterday to *zip* two list together.

You pass in two lists, and a `BiFunction` that uses an element from each list and creates a new element to add to the result list:

```
public static <T, S, R> List<R> zip(List<? extends T> l1, List<? extends S> l2,
    BiFunction<? super T, ? super S, R> zipper) {

    int size = Math.min(l1.size(), l2.size());
    List<R> result = new ArrayList<>();

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        result.add(zipper.apply(l1.get(i), l2.get(i)));

    return result;
}
```

Use like so:

```
class A {...}
class B {...}

class C { // Combination of A and B
    ...
    public C(name, number, emailId, userId, imageUrl) {...} // Types ommitted

    // public C(A a, B b) {...} // <-- optionally this, you could just pass C::new
    ...
}
```

```
List<A> list1 = ...;
List<B> list2 = ...;

List<C> list3 = zip(list1, list2, 
    (a, b) -> new C(a.getName(), a.getNumber(), a.getEmailID(),
        b.getUserId(), b.getImageUrl())); // Use appropriate getters.
```

---

I couldn't find something like this in the Java API.

Comment: BiFunction class requires API level 24 or higher. so Can't use it. here is a reference for the same https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/function/BiFunction.html

Comment: @Jigar You could easily implement it yourself: ```interface BiFunction<T, S, R> { R apply(T, S); }``` (which still lacks the ```andThen```, but that's not needed here)

Comment: Ok I'll try with this approach

Answer (score 0):

For PHP - **[Live Demo](https://onlinephp.io/c/526ee)**

For your reference:- `array_merge()` used for merge two array
if set the condition `$item_one['number'] == $item_two['number']`

```
$array_one = array(
    array('name' => 'name1', 'number' => 1234),
    array('name' => 'name2', 'number' => 4567),
    array('name' => 'name3', 'number' => 6789)
);

$array_two = array(
    array('number' => 1234, 'userId' => 'u1'),
    array('number' => 4567, 'userId' => 'u2'),
    array('number' => 6789, 'userId' => 'u3')
);

$array_three = array(); 

foreach ($array_one as $item_one) {
    foreach ($array_two as $item_two) {
        if ($item_one['number'] == $item_two['number']) {
            $merged_both = array_merge($item_one, $item_two);
            $array_three[] = $merged_both;
        }
    }
}

print_r($array_three);
```

You can run the below code in online java compiler - **[Run Online Compiler](https://www.programiz.com/java-programming/online-compiler/)**

`List` and `Map` to represent the arrays, and it compares the "number" values to merge the items into a new list, `arraythree` array and also `Map.of` method is used to create immutable maps for simplicity.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class MergeArrays {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Map<String, Object>> arrayone = new ArrayList<>();
        arrayone.add(Map.of("name", "name1", "number", 1234));
        arrayone.add(Map.of("name", "name2", "number", 4567));
        arrayone.add(Map.of("name", "name3", "number", 6789));

        List<Map<String, Object>> arraytwo = new ArrayList<>();
        arraytwo.add(Map.of("number", 1234, "userId", "u1"));
        arraytwo.add(Map.of("number", 4567, "userId", "u2"));
        arraytwo.add(Map.of("number", 6789, "userId", "u3"));

        List<Map<String, Object>> arraythree = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Map<String, Object> itemA : arrayone) {
            for (Map<String, Object> itemB : arraytwo) {
                if (itemA.get("number").equals(itemB.get("number"))) {
                    Map<String, Object> mergedItem = new HashMap<>(itemA);
                    mergedItem.putAll(itemB);
                    arraythree.add(mergedItem);
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println(arraythree);
    }
}
```